# Typing a redux async action creator

Tags: typescript, redux

I'm trying to type this function, but I'm running into trouble

```
function createAsyncAction(actionName: ActionNames, functionName: String) {
  return function(
    ...params: any[]
  ): ActionCreator<ThunkAction<any, any, any, any>> {
    return async function(dispatch, getState, client, any) {
      dispatch({ type: `${actionName}_REQUESTING`, status: REQUESTING });
      try {
        let result = null;
        if (client[functionName]) {
          result = await client[functionName].apply(this, params);
        }
        dispatch({ type: `${actionName}_SUCCESS`, payload: result });
      } catch (e) {
        dispatch({ type: `${actionName}_FAILURE`, error: e.message });
      }
    };
  };
}
```

I get an error for the `ActionCreator<ThunkAction<any,any,any,any>>` type.

This is the error

```
Type '(dispatch: any, getState: any, client: any, any: any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreator<ThunkAction<any, any, any, any>>'.
  Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'ThunkAction<any, any, any, any>'.
    Type 'Promise<any>' provides no match for the signature '(dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>, getState: () => any, extraArgument: any): any'.
```

However, I don't understand why this error is happening, probably because I don't fully understand what ThunkAction is doing.

What is going wrong?

Comment: `ActionCreator<ThunkAction<any,any,any,any>>` => `Promise<any>`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solid understanding of redux-thunk either, but moving the `ActionCreator<ThunkAction<any, any, any, any>>` return type annotation to the outer `createAsyncAction` function seems to make the error go away and I think it is probably what you intend.